# Windows path substitution

Tags: windows, filesystems, symbolic-link

Is there a command for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 R2 where you can perform a file system path substitution?

I have a SQL server database that has the following file paths hard coded:

> C:\SomeOldPath\That\I\CannotChange\SomeFile.pdf
> C:\SomeOtherOldPath\That\I\CannotChange\SomeFile2.docx
> C:\SomeOtherOldPath\That\I\Also\CannotChange\SomeFile2.docx

These files are actually located at:

> E:\SomeNewPath\That\I\CannotChange\SomeFile.pdf
> F:\SomeOtherNewPath\That\I\CannotChange\SomeFile2.docx
> F:\SomeOtherNewPath\That\I\Also\CannotChange\SomeFile2.docx

So basically I want to map:

> C:\SomeOldPath --> E:\SomeNewPath
>
> C:\SomeOtherOldPath --> F:\SomeOtherNewPath

It appears that mklink will do this under Windows 7 but I cannot seem to find it under Windows Server 2012 R2. Any ideas where it might be hiding?

Comment: Have you run the command `mklink /?` from command prompt? According to TechNet, mklink is included in Server 2012: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

Comment: it is not available from PowerShell but if I run cmd then I can get to it from there.

Comment: That would be helpful to specify next time, just for future questions. Tell exactly what you've tried, and where

Comment: I only discovered that AFTER I saw the answer and your comment, hence it was not in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a junction in Windows 7 or 2012 using the MKLINK command.

mklink /j source-path target-path

Example:

mklink /j C:\FileName1 C:\Temp\FileName2